# The client IP address format in a WCF service

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, ip, wcf-binding

I'm using the latest WCF version. I'm getting the client's IP address like that:

```
        OperationContext context = OperationContext.Current;
        MessageProperties prop = context.IncomingMessageProperties;
        RemoteEndpointMessageProperty endpoint = prop[RemoteEndpointMessageProperty.Name] as RemoteEndpointMessageProperty;
        string ip = endpoint.Address;
```

The IP I get is:

> ::1

What does it mean, can someone explain me this format?

Is it because of the binding? I use `basicHttpBinding`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is the IPv6 loopback address

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Localhost

i.e. The client is on the same machine and is connecting to the service using IPv6

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. Is it possible to get client's IPv4 ?

Comment: As it happens, this is very close to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2028879/ipv4-remote-address-in-wcf which has some suggestions

Comment: I saw that. The answer is from 2010 though, and it basically says _"I'm not aware of any WCF setting to enforce that - you'd have to dig into the network stack and see if there's any way to make it use IPv4 addresses instead of IPv6."_ So I was wondering if there is a way to normalize a client's IP address (so I will log IP in just one format)

Comment: It's basically about which network protocols you support. In a _not so very helpful_ way, I don't know how you would disable IPv6 in the service as it's actually handled at a much lower level in the OS. You could maybe attempt to lookup the IPv4 address?... I've just found this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ipaddress.maptoipv4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: Thanks, I will look into it